# How can I active auto completion for p5js in WebStrom?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I'm trying to get auto completing running in [WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/). I tried this one but it's not working: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#

Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try installing p5 typings: in **Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries**, press **Downloads...**, select `p5` from the list.

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2020.1/configuring-javascript-libraries.html#ws_jsconfigure_libraries_ts_definition_files

Comment: Thank you! :) I'm trying this.